# scrapy Crawl spider Multiple queries

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, google-search

I am trying to find email ids, i have a list and i want to pass multiple search query one after the other, but when i try using list in shows me and indentation error , can anyone help me solve with the issue?

my code is here:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Request
from googlesearch import search
import re
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("")
sh = wb.active()

class email_extractor(CrawlSpider):
    
    name = 'email_ex'

    def __init__(self,query, *args, **kwargs):
        super(email_extractor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.email_list = []
        self.query = query

    # sending requests

    def start_requests(self):
         
        for results in search(self.query, num=10, stop=None, pause=2):
            yield SeleniumRequest(
                url=results,
                callback=self.parse,
                wait_until=EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.TAG_NAME, "html")),
                dont_filter=True
            )

    # extracting emails
    def parse(self, response):
        EMAIL_REGEX = r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+'
        emails = re.finditer(EMAIL_REGEX, str(response.text))
        for email in emails:
            self.email_list.append(email.group())

        for email in set(self.email_list):
            yield{
                "emails": email
            }

        self.email_list.clear()
```

I want to pass the list containing multiple domains in search_query=['info' 'contact' , 'sales','marketing','market places']
can anyone help me find the solution for this?

Comment: Please post the full traceback and error message you are receiving

Comment: Not the error code is working fine i just wanna know how can i search list of queries at a time using a for loop? can this code be modified to something like that?

Comment: it already does do that... your for loop in the start_requests method returns a sequence and the for loop iterates over each of the items in the sequence.

Comment: Nope my for loop in requests is finding urls of one query and yieleding selenium req to them ,But the search query is called when constructor is intantiantezed.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for... please try to clarify

Comment: i have a list of multiple queries, come to the line def__init__( self,*args,**kwargs):   self.query=query(Here only i am able to pass a single query, like for example "market places @gmail.com", but i want to pass mutiple queries which will process one after the other, the code runs from the terminal and i am not able to pass a list and loop through it, can you help me find a way in which i can use this code to pass multiple queries which will process after completion of first.

Answer (score 0):

Still not 100% sure if I understand the issue but here is an example of how you could process a list of queries instead of just one query.

```
    def __init__(self,query, *args, **kwargs):
        super(email_extractor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.email_list = []
        self.queries = [query1,query2,query3,query4]  # list of queries

    # sending requests

    def start_requests(self):
        for query in self.queries:  # iterate through queries
            for results in search(query, num=10, stop=None, pause=2):
                yield SeleniumRequest(
                    url=results,
                    callback=self.parse,
                    wait_until=EC.presence_of_element_located(
                        (By.TAG_NAME, "html")),
                    dont_filter=True
                )
```

Comment: sure i will check and let you know if it works